# Forcing in an ASP classic window the VBScript code to wait after calling an ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, vbscript, window, wait

i have the next scenario (which I cannot change) in an ASP classic page:

VBScriptCode ....

```
var w
w=window.open(...)
```

VBScriptCode ....

In window.open I call an ASP.NET window. What I want to do is to force the VBScriptCode after the javascript block, to wait and no execute till the ASP.NET window deletes a file (Because actually the ASP.NET window begins to execute after the VBScriptCode second block). I have tried the next two things:

1)

```
while oFsoLocal.FileExists(filaAddress)     
wend
```

2)

```vb
file_exist=True
while file_exist
    setTimeOut(file_exist=oFsoLocal.FileExists(fileAddress),1000)
wend
```

But without any success.

Comment: Is the vbscript code server side and the javascript client side?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming server side code here and if you have access to MSSQL, this function assumes you already have the DB open with my_conn

```
Function waitfor(sleep) ' if you need more than 59 seconds, you will need to adjust the SQL
  sql = "WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:" & right(clng(sleep),2) & "'"
  my_conn.Execute sql,,129
End function
```